# show data that exists in both MYSQL tables and/or R objects

Tags: mysql, r, overlap

i think its an regular problem, answered several times, but I just don't know how to ask the question right =(

in MySQL:
i have 2 tables with some kind of strings inside, now i want:
1. the data that occur in both tables
2. the data from a that is not in table b

same in R:
i have 2 R data.frame s and i want:
1. the data that occur in a and b
2. the data that occur in a but not in b

Comment: R: So your two data frames are 'a' and 'b'? And you want to find the instances where the whole row of the data frame (which could be several values) are the same between 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: Really, you could perform both of these operations in R using RMySQL

Comment: joshua and ErVeY got me right, they gave the solution! both in R?? why same thing twice ? just wanted to know how it works in both =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `R`:

```
a <- data.frame(V1=sample(letters[1:3],20,TRUE),V2=rnorm(20))
b <- data.frame(V1=sample(letters[2:4],20,TRUE),V2=rnorm(20))

# the data that occur in a and b
(ab <- merge(a,b,by="V1"))

# the data that occur in a but not in b 
aNOTb <- merge(a,b,by="V1",all=TRUE)
(aNOTb <- aNOTb[is.na(aNOTb$V2.y),])
```

Answer (score 3):

in mysql you could do this to get the data in both tables

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

and do this to get the tada from a that is not in table b

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```